# Change background color of input field as long as there is text entered with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a few input fields in a table that start out as white, change to yellow when mouse over, and
change to green as long as there is text in the box. My issue is, when I move the mouse out of the box I want it to go back to white if it's empty, but stay green if there is text entered. Right now, if I move the mouse back over an input field with text in it, it turns yellow and then goes back to white when I mouse out.

Is there any way to give an event precedence, or use *if* to make the other events contingent with Javascript or html?

**JAVASCRIPT and HTML**

```js
function toYellow(element){   //change fields to yellow
    if (element == 1)
       document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    else if (element == 2)
        document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    else
        document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
 }

 function toWhite(element){   // change fields to white
    if (element == 1)
       document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    else if (element == 2)
        document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    else
        document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
 }


 function toGreen(element){   // change fields to green
    if (element == 1)
       document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else if (element == 2)
        document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    else
        document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
 }
```

```html
<tr><td> Toys ($5.00 each)</td>  <td><input id="item3" type="number"
    onmouseout="toWhite(3)" onmouseover="toYellow(3)" onkeydown="toGreen(3)"> </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check whether the element has a value in it, if yes then change it's color to green.

In the below code snippet I have just handled the condition for checking a single input field (item3) but you need to add a check for all the possible input fields in each function to have the field value always green if there is text in it.

```js
function toYellow(element){   //change fields to yellow
    if (document.getElementById("item3").value) {
      document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "green"
    return;
    }
      if (element == 1)
         document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      else if (element == 2)
          document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      else
          document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
   }

   function toWhite(element){   // change fields to white
   if (document.getElementById("item3").value) {
      document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "green"
    return;
    }
      if (element == 1)
         document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      else if (element == 2)
          document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      else
          document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
   }


   function toGreen(element){   // change fields to green
   if (document.getElementById("item3").value) {
      document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "green"
    return;
    }
      if (element == 1)
         document.getElementById("item1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      else if (element == 2)
          document.getElementById("item2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      else
          document.getElementById("item3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
   }
```

```html
<tr><td> Toys ($5.00 each)</td>  <td><input id="item3" type="number"
    onmouseout="toWhite(3)" onmouseover="toYellow(3)" onkeydown="toGreen(3)"> </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation :**

First of all, you can access the element by `this`, being passed as a parameter in the functions. You don't have to access elements using ids for that.

Now, when input is being added in the `input box` is typed, `toYellow()` and `toWhite()` do not get executed. I have replaced the `keydown` event listener with `oninput`. This makes sure that even if you don't type in, and use arrows to add input, `toGreen()` gets executed.

```js
function toYellow(curEl) { //change fields to yellow
  if(!curEl.value.trim())
    curEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function toWhite(curEl) { // change fields to white
  if(!curEl.value.trim())
    curEl.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function toGreen(curEl) { // change fields to green
  curEl.style.backgroundColor = (curEl.value.trim()) ? "green" : "white";
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td> Toys ($5.00 each)</td>
  <td><input id="item3" type="number" onmouseout="toWhite(this)" onmouseover="toYellow(this)" oninput="toGreen(this)"> </td>
</tr>
```